# Adding a title to R openair timeplot

Tags: r, csv, plot

I am using R's openair package to plot time series of over a hundred .csv files. I can generate the plot but I am not able to add a title to the plot. In addition, I would like the title to be the site location which I can pull from either the file name or the first column in the .csv file. It looks like you can do this using the auto.text of the timeplot function but I am not having any luck. Is it possible to add the title in the fashion? If so, how can it be done?

```
library(openair)

filedir <- "C:/Users/dfmcg/Documents/Thesis files/ALL_GPMP_O3_Met"
myfiles <- c(list.files(path = filedir))
paste(filedir, myfiles,sep = '/')
npsfiles <- c(paste(filedir, myfiles,sep = '/'))

for (i in npsfiles[1:3]){
  timeozone <- import(i, date="DATE", date.format = "%m/%d/%Y %H", header = TRUE,
                      na.strings = "-999", auto.text(main = ("ABBR")))
  timePlot(timeozone, pollutant = c("O3"))
}
```

And here is a small part of the data:

```
ABBR     DATE          O3   SWS  VWS  SWD  VWD 
ZION-DW 01/01/2004 00 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 
ZION-DW 01/01/2004 01 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999
```

Answer (score 1):

You man want to use the main attribute of timePlot with your site location as a string option to it.

```
title = 'Site location'
timePlot(mydata, pollutant = "nox", main = title)
```

Comment: This put a title on my graph by did not successfully cycle through my file and add the appropriate title. It helped to to figure out where to go next though. Thanks!